# How do I remove tabs?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am having problem with removing tabs in Linux scripting. I have this in my script:

```
df -h | awk 'NR>1' | awk '{print$1}' | column -t
df -h | awk 'NR>1' | awk '{print$5}' | column -t
```

which would obviously give an output like this:

**/directory1**

**/directory2**

**/directory3**

**/directoryn**

**45%**

**32%**

**xx%**

**x%**

But if I do it this way:

```
df -h | awk 'NR>1' | awk '{print$1,$5}' | column -t
```

The output will be like this:

**/directory1 (TAB) 45%**

**/directory2 (TAB) 32%**

**/directory3 (TAB) xx%**

**/directoryn (TAB) xx%**

but I want the output to be like this:

**/directory1 45%**

**/directory2 32%**

**/directory3 xx%**

**/directoryn x%**

I really hope you guys could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of your pipe to column completely, or omit the -t switch

Comment: That works. Thanks. I was close. I just made my life more complicated. lol

Comment: Glad to help, but please accept this as the correct answer too :)

Comment: @endlesslearning Also, you don't need two pipes for `awk`. This should suffice - `df -h | awk 'NR>1{print $1,$5}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `printf` in `awk` if you want to find tune the spacing, for example:

```
df -h | awk 'NR>1' | awk '/^\// { printf("%-12s %5s\n", $1, $5) }'
```

Yields:

```
/dev/sdb7      82%
/dev/sdb1      28%
/dev/sdb5      75%
/dev/sda1      79%
```

(I also only select those lines that started with `/`.)